# WCF and plain-text credentials: Custom SecurityAlgorithmSuite?

Tags: wcf, ws-security

So out of the box, WCF doesn't allow me to send WS-Security credentials plain-text as they are expected by CXF on the receiving end.  It seems as though different SecurityAlgorithmSuite which doesn't actually encrypt anything would do the trick, but I don't know where to begin as far as what values should be returned by the various properties in my "PlainTextSecurityAlgorithmSuite".  Has anyone done this?  Am I correct in thinking this would solve my problem?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the binding details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this custom [binding](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html). It allows sending plain text UserName token on unsecured channel.

Comment: Yeah, so sorry for the *very* late response.  It wasn't until the other day that the work-load slowed enough for me to go back and try this. The custom binding in your link performs exactly as advertised! Unfortunately, that only got me part of the way to the solution. With the username and password in clear-text, we're relying on SSL to provide the real security. Out of the box, that binding doesn't support https. The fix was simple however - just change the transport element to extend HttpsTransportBindingElement rather than the Http version. (continued below...)

Comment: I found that the axis service I was calling doesn't include security envelope in it's response and .NET no likey. So after a bit more research I found a Knowledge Base article and hotfix - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971493  This hot fix adds a new propert to the TransportSecurityBindingElement - EnableUnsecuredResponse. Setting this to true tells the .NET client to use security on the request, but ignore it (or the lack of it) on the response. BINGO! Working solution! Thank you SO MUCH for that binding, which was the key to getting the rest to work.